How to return to efifb without reboot (re activate vga console)?
When I boot my Linux machine, I have only efifb framebuffer device available at first:
[    0.642906] efifb: probing for efifb
[    0.642954] efifb: No BGRT, not showing boot graphics
[    0.642957] efifb: framebuffer at 0xe0000000, using 1920k, total 1920k
[    0.642962] efifb: mode is 800x600x32, linelength=3200, pages=1
[    0.642966] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.642968] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    0.643232] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
[    0.644628] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device

But later in the boot process (or manually, if nomodeset was passed), GPU specific drivers can be loaded. For example:
[   85.217573] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   85.257703] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20230929 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   85.259459] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   85.278163] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input22
[   85.279215] i915 display info: display version: 7
[   85.279222] i915 display info: cursor_needs_physical: no
[   85.279224] i915 display info: has_cdclk_crawl: no
[   85.279226] i915 display info: has_cdclk_squash: no
[   85.279227] i915 display info: has_ddi: no
[   85.279229] i915 display info: has_dp_mst: no
[   85.279230] i915 display info: has_dsb: no
[   85.279232] i915 display info: has_fpga_dbg: no
[   85.279233] i915 display info: has_gmch: no
[   85.279235] i915 display info: has_hotplug: yes
[   85.279236] i915 display info: has_hti: no
[   85.279238] i915 display info: has_ipc: no
[   85.279239] i915 display info: has_overlay: no
[   85.279241] i915 display info: has_psr: no
[   85.279242] i915 display info: has_psr_hw_tracking: no
[   85.279243] i915 display info: overlay_needs_physical: no
[   85.279245] i915 display info: supports_tv: no
[   85.279246] i915 display info: has_hdcp: no
[   85.279248] i915 display info: has_dmc: no
[   85.279249] i915 display info: has_dsc: no
[   85.304115] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   85.444292] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   85.464113] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device

Since then, even if I unload the GPU specific driver (for example with echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind + rmmod i915), I still can't restore the efifb device. Is it possible to return to the efifb device after a GPU specific driver was loaded?
